# Electron kill child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron app that uses `child_process.exec` to run long running tasks. 
 I am struggling to manage when the user exits the app during those tasks.

If they exit my app or hit close the child processes continue to run until they finish however the electron app window has already closed and exited.

Is there a way to notify the user that there are process still running and when they have finished then close the app window?

All I have in my `main.js` is the standard code:

```
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

Should I be adding a check somewhere?

Thanks for your help

EDITED

I cannot seem to get the PID of the `child_process` until it has finished. This is my `child_process` code

```
var loader = child_process.exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(loader.pid)
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    console.log('Loaded: ', value);
});
```

Should I be trying to get it in a different way?

Comment: What is the desired behavior, to automatically kill the child process when the app is closed or to actually let it continue until completion and then automatically close?

Comment: @mscdex it would be great to kill all child processes then exit the app Would that be possible?

Comment: Also, you should get pids whenever you're calling `child processes` and kill it through that.

Comment: @shriek I have tried to get the PID but it only gives me the PID at the end of the process. I must not be doing it right. I have edited my initial question to include that bit of the script. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: For long running tasks ```child_process.spawn``` with ```{ detached: true }```  is more suitable, i'm already using it in my electron app.

Comment: @tjmgis - IIRC, the callback on `child_process.exec` only runs after the process exits. You need to get `loader.exec` outside of the callback.

Comment: @MariusDarila thank you very much for recommending child_process.spawn. For me it works so much better than exec. Super helpful

Comment: @shriek using pids ended up being the best way

Comment: @tjmgis glad that you got it figured out. I've been afk for quite some time.

Comment: "windows-all-closed" is also not the right event to listen for since it may or may not be called depending on how the app is closed. "before-quit" is always called-
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#event-before-quit

Answer (score 24):

So after everyones great comments I was able to update my code with a number of additions to get it to work, so am posting my updates for everyone else.

1) Change from child_process.exec to child_process.spawn

`var loader = child_process.spawn('program', options, { detached: true })`

2) Use the Electron ipcRenderer to communicate from my module to the main.js script. This allows me to send the PIDs to main.js

`ipcRenderer.send('pid-message', loader.pid);`

```
ipcMain.on('pid-message', function(event, arg) {
  console.log('Main:', arg);
  pids.push(arg);
});
```

3) Add those PIDs to array

4) In my main.js I added the following code to kill any PIDs that exist in the array before exiting the app.

```
// App close handler
app.on('before-quit', function() {
  pids.forEach(function(pid) {
    // A simple pid lookup
    ps.kill( pid, function( err ) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error( err );
        }
        else {
            console.log( 'Process %s has been killed!', pid );
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Hey this is a really good solution that fixed a problem I had. I'm disappointed there's no 'destructor' function when the Renderer process exits, it would make cleanup like this a lot easier!

Comment: This looks like it depends on the `ps-node` package, is that right?

Answer (score 6):

`ChildProcess` emits an `exit` event when the process has finished - if you  keep track of the current processes in an array, and have them remove themselves after the `exit` event fires, you should be able to just `foreach` over the remaining ones running `ChildProcess.kill()` when you exit your app.

This may not be 100% working code/not the best way of doing things, as I'm not in a position to test it right now, but it should be enough to set you down the right path.

```
var processes = [];

// Adding a process
var newProcess = child_process.exec("mycommand");
processes.push(newProcess);
newProcess.on("exit", function () {
  processes.splice(processes.indexOf(newProcess), 1);
});

// App close handler
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    processes.forEach(function(proc) {
      proc.kill();
    });

    app.quit();
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** As shreik mentioned in a comment, you could also just store the PIDs in the array instead of the `ChildProcess` objects, then use `process.kill(pid)` to kill them. Might be a little more efficient!

Comment: i kept getting an error saying proc.kill(); was not a function

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution**. If you want to keep using `exec()`

In order to kill the child process running by `exec()` take a look to the module [`ps-tree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-tree). They exaplain what is happening.

> in UNIX, a process may terminate by using the exit call, and it's
>   parent process may wait for that event by using the wait system call.
>   the wait system call returns the process identifier of a terminated
>   child, so that the parent tell which of the possibly many children has
>   terminated. If the parent terminates, however, all it's children have
>   assigned as their new parent the init process. Thus, the children
>   still have a parent to collect their status and execution statistics.
>   (from "operating system concepts")
>
> **SOLUTION:** use `ps-tree` to get all processes that a `child_process` may have started, so that they

`exec()` actually works like this:

```javascript
function exec (cmd, cb) {
  spawn('sh', ['-c', cmd]);
  ...
}
```

So check the example and adapt it to your needs

```javascript
var cp = require('child_process'),
psTree = require('ps-tree');

var child = cp.exec("node -e 'while (true);'", function () { /*...*/ });

psTree(child.pid, function (err, children) {
    cp.spawn('kill', ['-9'].concat(children.map(function (p) { return p.PID })));
});
```