# Is there an ElectronJS 'cleanup' function/event when the Renderer process exits?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, electron, child-process

I recently used this [4-year old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031465/electron-kill-child-process-exec) to properly kill Node `child_process`es that I fork in the ElectronJS Renderer thread. The idea is to send the PIDs to the main thread to kill on `app.quit` via IPC. This seems like a serious hack. Isn't there some kind of `before-exit` or cleanup function in the Renderer thread that can be hooked to do this work?

Adding a handler to `process.on('exit'...)` in the Render process does not accomplish this (nor does `beforeExit`).

Comment: You can try `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", callback)`. This will be called when the browserWindow is exiting or when the page is about to reload.

Comment: I'm getting: `addEventListener` doesn't exist on `window`.

Comment: I'm talking about the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object, not the `browserWindow` instance. I don't see your code so I don't know what you are doing but this should definitely work.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I was looking for an Electron solution, didn't occur to me to use a native solution. Thanks!